# Смена значения переменной

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть переменная `document.turn = "Text 1"`, мне нужно, чтобы её значение `Text 1` сменялось последовательно с `Text 2`. То есть при первом использовании `document.turn` - `Text 1`, при втором - `Text 2`. Надеюсь сможете мне помочь, заранее большое спасибо.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function onClick(sender) {
            document.turn = "X"
            if (sender.innerText == ""){
              sender.innerHTML = document.turn
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table frame="void" align="center">
        <tbody>  
        <tr>
            <td id="c1" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c2" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c3" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c4" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c5" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c6" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c7" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c8" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            <td id="c9" class="Square" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: а гдн код? вам просто надо узнать как можно увчеличить число в строке?

Comment: Последовательно менять Text 1 и Text 2.

Comment: @A.Hall, как именно вы **используете**?

Comment: при клике на ячейку вставляется document.turn

Comment: вот и добавьте этот код в вопрос

Comment: @A.Hall, где-нибудь еще в коде вы используете `document.turn` или это единственное место?

Comment: Это единственное место, это имеет значение?

Comment: конечно имеет, в данном случае эта переменная вообще не нужна. у вас только два возможных варианта?

Comment: Да, только два.

Comment: то есть смотрите, после первого стало `"X"` что должно быть после второго и третьего клика? выставиться какое-то значение или вернуться пустая строка?

Comment: После второго должно быть "O", после третьего опять "X" и так далее...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае достаточно ветки `else` в котором будет происходить смена между `x` и `o`

```
function onClick(sender) {
    var steps = {"X":"O", "O":"X"}; //порядок смен, после X->O, после O->X
    if (sender.innerText == ""){
      sender.innerHTML = "X";//если первый раз - устанавливаем X
    }else{
      sender.innerHTML = steps[sender.innerText];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** для комментария

```
var steps = {"X":"O", "O":"X"}; //порядок смен, после X->O, после O->X
var current = "X";

function onClick(sender) {
    if (sender.innerText == ""){// если пустая ячейка
      sender.innerHTML = current; //устанавливаем текущее значение
      current = steps[current];//меняем на следующее
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного не так, мне нужно, чтобы это происходило в разных ячейках, то есть кликнули на одну ячейку - "X", кликнули на другую - "O", при этом если кликнуть на "X" или "O" ещё раз, то ничего не должно происходить.

Comment: @A.Hall, обновил ответ

Comment: Да, всё работает! Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

> После второго должно быть "O", после третьего опять "X" и так далее...

В таком случае объявляете две строковые константы и, в зависимости от того, какой текст находится в данный момент в ячейке таблицы выводите нужную из них.

```
function onClick(sender) {
            var text1="X";
            var text2="0";
            if (sender.innerHTML=="")
            {

                if (document.turn==text1)
                {
                    sender.innerHTML=text2
                }
                else
                {
                    sender.innerHTML=text1
                }
               document.turn= sender.innerHTML;
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: Немного не так, мне нужно, чтобы это происходило в разных ячейках, то есть кликнули на одну ячейку - "X", кликнули на другую - "O", при этом если кликнуть на "X" или "O" ещё раз, то ничего не должно происходить.

Comment: @A.Hall, для этого делается проверка равно ли содержимое ячейки некоторому начальному значению. Код в ответе поправил.

Comment: Да, всё работает! Спасибо большое за помощь!