# Ячейки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть таблица c 4 ячейками и два текста ("Text 1" и "Text 2").
При клике на каждую ячейку в ней последовательно появляется сначала "Text 1", затем "Text 2" и так до тех пор, пока все ячейки не будут заполнены. При клике на уже "кликнутую ячейку" ничего не произойдёт: текст появляется только при клике на пустую ячейку.

**Мне нужно**: если в ячейке `с1` и `с2` есть либо два "Text 1", либо два "Text 2" (то есть в ячейках `с1` и `с2` есть только Text 1 (в каждой) или Text 2 (в каждой)), то пользователь, кликая на другие ячейки, не может получать того же эффекта, которого получал ранее.

Надеюсь, что сможете мне помочь решить эту проблему, заранее большое спасибо.

```
    var steps = {"Text 1":"Text 2", "Text 2":"Text 1"}; 
    var current = "Text 1";
   function onClick(sender) {
      if (sender.innerText == ""){
        sender.innerHTML = current; 
        current = steps[current];
        }}
    </script>

<table border="1" cellpadding="50px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="c1" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        <td id="c2" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td id="c3" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        <td id="c4" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ссылка на fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anvolvolckov/b1j3sm3b/#&togetherjs=AvDy3NPzhA

Comment: Я не понимаю вот этой фразы: "пользователь, кликая на другие ячейки не может получать того же эффекта, которого получал ранее"... А что должно происходить?

Comment: @cyadvert, игра закончилась :-) крестики нолики же, не узнали? :)

Comment: тогда что ж таблица 2х2? И почему речь идет только о `c1` и `c2`?

Comment: @cyadvert, а это потому что пример :-) посмотрите остальные вопросы автора :) Например: [Смена значения переменной](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480280/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) вполне себе 3*3

Comment: @Grundy, вы абсолютно правы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В начало функции `onClick` нужно добавить нужную вам проверку:

```
if ((document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML === "Text 1"
 && document.getElementById("c2").innerHTML === "Text 1") ||
    (document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML === "Text 2"
 && document.getElementById("c2").innerHTML === "Text 2")) {
 return;
}
```

[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1j3sm3b/3/)

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно! Спасибо большое!